# 10.7 Launchd + rvm

Tags: launchd, macos

This question fits somewhere between server fault, stackoverflow and askdifferent.

I am installing some web apps on my Lion server using webappctl, which hooks into apaches vhost configs to setup up a reverse proxy (simply mod_proxy). It uses launchd to start the server, in my case unicorn serving a Ruby on Rails app, listening on TCP port 5000. I use RVM (mixed-mode) to facilitate in separate ruby versions and gemsets for each webapp.

The problem lies with RVM and launchd, and the complete environment not being available for launchd.

I tried to start from launchd using `/bin/bash -l -c 'unicorn_rails -l 5000'` but that gave me bash usage errors in the logs.

Any suggestions for making RVM play nice with launchd?

Comment: This question would get a better response on Superuser

Comment: A lot of Apple related questions are being migrated to **Ask Different** that really shouldn't be. The level of technical knowledge on Ask Different is low compared to **StackOverflow**, **ServerFault**, and **SuperUser**. Just because it's Apple hardware/software doesn't mean it doesn't belong on those sites! So stop migrating just because some Win or open source troll sees the word `Mac`

Comment: What were the bash errors?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make a `RVM`-based `rake` command work with `launchd`:

```
/bin/bash -l -c '/absolute/path/to/myscript.sh'
```

My script was calling `rake`. I wasn't calling it directly.

Have you tried using an absolute path for your `unicorn_rails`?

The `.plist` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> <plist version="1.0"> <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>mylabel</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/bin/bash</string>
                <string>-l</string>
                <string>-c</string>
                <string>/absolute/path/to/myscript.sh</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Hour</key>
                <integer>10</integer>
                <key>Minute</key>
                <integer>00</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict> 
</plist>
```

Comment: Good call! One little-known security nit about launchd executables is that they must not be alterable by anyone but root. Since relative paths mean the output goes into the invoking directory, that means that launchd tries to run it's output into root ("/"), which is a no-no.